# how to set a border around circle image view like instagram?

Tags: android, geometry, imageview, instagram

i want to set a circle border around circle image view like instagram stories,any one can help?
here is my image view

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/profile_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile1"
    app:civ_border_color="#DBDBDB"
    app:civ_border_width="1dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also use the **`ShapeableImageView`** provided by the Material Components Library.

Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/circularImageView"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/...."
    app:strokeColor="@color/....."
    app:strokeWidth="1dp"
    ...
    />
```

with:

```
  <style name="circularImageView">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version **`1.2.0-alpha03`**.

Comment: the master of material design returns :)

Answer (score 0):

**Circle image view like instagram stories**

I have found a new method and you should also try this.  I have had great success with this method. From this you can get an Instagram-style circle image view.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/instagram_boder_color.xml"/>


            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                app:civ_border_color="@color/white"
                app:civ_border_width="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_boder_color.xml"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

with: create two drawable like this...

create drawable 1 = instagram_boder_color.xml" with shape  android:shape="oval"

```
<gradient
    android:startColor="#DD129D"
    android:endColor="#FBC02D"
    />
```

create drawable 2 = white_boder_color.xml" with shape  android:shape="oval"

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"></solid>
```

[out put: boder color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2njg.jpg)